# How to point an R function to a particular column of a dataset?

Tags: r

I have a dataset called *df*, which has columns *a* and *b* with three integers each. I want to write a function for the mean (obviously this already exists; I want to write a larger function and this appears to be where problems are occurring). However, this function returns NA:

```
mean_function <- function(x) {
mean(df$x)
}
```

`mean_function(a)` returns `NA`, while `mean(df$a)` returns `2`. Is there something I'm missing about how R functions handle datasets, or another problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need `[[` instead of `$` as it will literally check for `x` as column and pass a string

```
mean_function <- function(x) {mean(df[[x]])}
mean_function("a")
```

If we need to pass unquoted column name, `substitute` and convert to `character` with `deparse`

```
mean_function<- function(x) {
       x <- deparse(substitute(x))
       mean(df[[x]]
 }

mean_function(a)
```